# Secrets Scanning for Atlassian Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, secret-management

I am looking for:

A plugin on Atlassian Bitbucket which would help us run scan on entire code to detect any hardcoded secrets

A tool/script which could be run in a pipeline right after the code is cloned (to detect any hardcoded secrets)

A tool which could be automatically triggered as soon as a code is checked in (to detect any hardcoded secrets)

Based on your experience, which tool would you recommend for the above?

I am open to both open source and licensed software suggestions.